# Creating a full screen background image, But still allowing users to scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a website that all fits on one page and scrolls down to other sections that will act like other pages. Id like to have a landing page that is a dynamically readjusting image, that will take up the entire page of the user when they enter. I was able to get the image to work, but im not able to scroll the page down to other content.

```
.full-size {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.page-welcome{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background: #292929 url(http://placekitten.com/1600/900) repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;  
    }
```

Heres the css I'm using.

I also set up and example in jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tm2v6/)
Please note that "Test" should be centered, must of copy pasted wrong or somthing.

Comment: Have you tried `background: #292929 url(http://placekitten.com/1600/900) repeat scroll;`?

Comment: Yeah, tried it with no luck

Comment: It's late so I may be misunderstanding your question, but have you tried adding `overflow:auto;` to your `.page-welcome` class, then setting the `margin-top` to 100%? I made [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tm2v6/11/), let me know if it accomplishes what you wanted

Comment: @Elle Actually the time explains it not surprises. I was playing with his fiddle, you commented, I didn't refreshed my page,so I missed your comment. Anyway I deleted answer, give a goal :)

Comment: @AtanuCSE, you didn't have to delete your answer, I believed you. Go ahead and put it back up it's fine.:)

Comment: You'll need to use javascript to calculate the viewport size, then size each 'page' of your overall page to fit.

Comment: @user3311827, did you get a chance to test my suggestion as of yet?

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on my comment: Adding `margin-top:100%;` to the div you are wanting to push down should yield the desired results. Please see the link below, I added a `div` called "test" with that property and it appears to accomplish what you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/tm2v6/13/embedded/result/